# a href not enclosed inside div tag

Tags: css, html, hyperlink

This is one that should be really simple to solve but I can't find a solution or explaination anywhere.

I have a text a href link inside a div tag but when I style the a:link with css I can't get the div tag to wrap around the a:link. Why is this and how do I fix this?

```
<style type="text/css">
#nav{
    background-color: #093;
}
a:link{
    height: 30px;
    width: 60px;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #CCC;
    border: solid #333 5px;
}
</style>

<div id="nav">
<a href="#">Link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: What do mean "wrap around".  Looks like you might want padding on the div, or to make the link a block or inline-block element (which appears to just have been submitted as an answer while I was writing the comment).

Comment: I won't to know why the #nav div won't enclose the a:href link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anchors are displayed `inline` by default. The parent will only take up the space that the **line** of the element takes up.

You need to display your anchor `inline-block`:

```
a:link{
    height: 30px;
    width: 60px;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #CCC;
    border: solid #333 5px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Jt4hN/)

Comment: I tried the display:inline-block; but it didn't do what I was looking for then I tried display:block; which worked.

Comment: I would have thought you would run into an issue with collapsing borders doing that, however yes, that will work with some tinkering. http://jsfiddle.net/Jt4hN/1/